# How to perform randomization test for categorical data and/or chi-square?

Tags: categorical-data, p-value, simulation

I am very newbie in statistics and I my problem is as follows: 
I have a total set of 20,000 categorical observations (this is my whole dataset, say DATA1) which has a certain proportion of "yes" and "no" Ex: (id-1: yes, id-2: yes, id-3: no, id-4: no, ... id-20,000: yes). From the whole dataset, I have a particular subset of 3,000 observations of my interest (say DATA2) (Ex: id-1: yes, id-2: yes etc.). I would like to test if the proportion of "yes"/"no" in this particular sample is significant higher/lower than the whole dataset. The first approach I suppose to do is a chi-square test, is it right? If so, how the table should look like?

Another approach that I am considering (and I think it is the most correct), is to random sample from the whole dataset (DATA1) 3,000 observations for N = 1000 rounds and count for each round the number of "yes" and "no". I suppose that I cannot plot the distribution and get z-scores because the variables are categorical. So, I'm stuck in this point because I don't know how to compare the simulated data with the observed data (DATA2) and finish with the statistical significance or computed p-values. Anyone could help me out on this problem? The easiest way to me is a solution in R.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there something special about your subsample? Why would you want to test those against the whole? Are they, eg, women, & you might want to see if they have the same % yes as the others (men)?

Comment: Yes, is there something special about the subsample. In that case It consists of a set of genes which have specific functions that I am interested in.

Comment: Just an idea (probably what @gung had in mind): Couldn't you simply test your subsample(s) against the rest of the data (instead of the whole data set)? Then you would be back to a simple 2xN contingency  table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fairly straightforward solution, without delving into your simulation idea.  It can be assessed as a modified $\chi^2$ Goodness of Fit question, where you treat DATA1 as a population, and DATA2 as your sample of interest.  The traditional null hypothesis for a GoF test is one of equal proportions (a test of 50% yeses versus 50% nos in your sample).  However, you can modify the test to check for differences from particular proportions of interest.  This is typically referred to as a test of "no differences from a known population".

So, what you could do is:

1. Using the full dataset, find the proportion of yeses and nos.  This is your "population of interest".  This can be done using `xtabs()` on DATA1. For example, perhaps you find 75% yes rate, and 25% no.
2. Use `chisq.test()` in the usual manner on your subset DATA2, but use the `p` argument to specify the probabilities that you obtained from the cross-tabulation.  Make sure to list them in order (e.g. if nos are coded in your dataset as 0s and yeses as 1s, then `p` should be entered as `p = c(p0, p1)`; using the example it would be entered as `p = c(.25, .75)`).

Comment: Thank you very much for replying my question. Your approach seems simple and very convenient, so I will try it! Many thanks! In respect to the simulation idea, do you think it is appropriate? I really appreciate  any suggestion on how to perform it.

Comment: Do you have a reference or perhaps a study on this approach? I can't figure out if this is actually a problem but using the same data twice doesn't feel right.

Comment: Did you mean to say "DATA1" twice in "*where you treat DATA1 as a population, and DATA1 as your sample*"?